# Retrieving normal function distribution from truncated normal distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, truncated-normal-distribution

I know that a random variable $S_t$ with known statistics $E(S_t)$ and $V(S_t)$ comes from the truncation (sub-sampling) on the interval $[0, +\infty]$ of a random $normal$ variable $S$ with PDF $N_S$ of statistics $E(S)$ and $V(S)$. I don't know $E(S)$ and $V(S)$ and I want to retrieve them.
I also know that the value of the $CDF_S(0)=A$.

Using the formula of the truncated normal (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution, [http://web.ist.utl.pt/~ist11038/compute/qc/,truncG/lecture4k.pdf](http://web.ist.utl.pt/%7Eist11038/compute/qc/,truncG/lecture4k.pdf)) I found that:

$E(S_t)=E(S)+\sqrt{V(S)} \frac{\phi(\alpha)}{1-A}$ with $\alpha= -E(S)/\sqrt{V(S)}$

$V(S_t)=V(S)(1+\frac{\alpha\phi(\alpha)}{1-A} -{(\frac{\phi(\alpha)}{1-A})}^2) = V(S)(1-\frac{E(S)\phi(\alpha)}{\sqrt{V(S)}(1-A)} -{(\frac{\phi(\alpha)}{1-A})}^2)$

I know that:

$N_S(0)=\frac{ 1}{ \sqrt{ 2 \pi V(S)}} e^{ -\frac{E(S)^2} {2V(S)}}$

Turning these equations in every directions, I cannot obtain a formula for the values of $E(S)$ and $V(S)$ knowing $E(S_t)$, $V(S_t)$ and $A$. Intuitively I expect that is is possible. How can I do ?

Comment: There are three equations connecting two parameters, since $E[S]+V(S)^{1/2}q_A=0$, if $q_A=\Phi^{-1}(A)$ for the standard cdf $\Phi(\cdot)$. Finding a closed form solution sounds unrealistic.

Comment: Thanks a lot Xi'an, your relation is magic ! It is what I was looking for. Could you please tell me how one can find it, or tell me its name if it is a well known formula ?

Comment: Uh?! I am simply expressing the quantile of a general Normal distribution in terms of the standard Normal cdf.

Answer (score 1):

RESOLVED

I finally found a solution thanks to Xi'an.

From Eq.1 we have:
$\frac{\phi(\alpha)}{1-A}=\frac{E(S_t)-E(S)}{\sqrt{V(S)}}$

Replacing it in Eq.2 gives:
$V(S_t)=V(S)+E(S)E(S_t)-E(S_t)^2$

Using Xi'an equation we can replace $V(S)$ by $E(S)^2/q_A^2$, so:

$V(S_t)=\frac{E(S)^2}{q_A^2}+E(S)E(S_t)-E(S_t)^2$

Its gives a second order equation on $E(S)$:

$aE(S)^2+bE(S)+c=0$

With:

$a=\frac{1}{q_A^2}$

$b=E(S_t)$

$c=-E(S_t)^2-V(S_t)$

It gives:

$E_{S1} = \frac{q_A^2[-E(S_t)-\sqrt{E(S_t)^2 - \frac{4(-E(S_t)^2-V(S_t))}{q_A^2}}]}{2}$

$E_{S2} = \frac{q_A^2[-E(S_t)+\sqrt{E(S_t)^2 - \frac{4(-E(S_t)^2-V(S_t))}{q_A^2}}]}{2}$

And with Xi'an equation

$V_{S1} = E_{S1}^2/q_A^2$

$V_{S2} = E_{S2}^2/q_A^2$

In my simulations, the correct result is given by $E_{S2}, V_{S2}$ don't know why.